# How can I set the created instance's property in Django-Rest-Framework CreateAPIView?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

How can I set the created instance's property in Django-Rest-Framework?

```
class ServerTaskCreateAPIView(CreateAPIView):
    serializer_class = PhysicalServerTaskCreateSerializer
    permission_classes = []
    queryset = ServerTask.objects.all()

    def perform_create(self, serializer):
        # I want to set the ServerTask instance to be `Initialed`
        # like instance.task_type = "Initialed"
        serializer.save()
```

You see, I tried to rewrite the `perform_create` method, and find there is no instance's param. how to access the requirement?

---

**edit**

I know I can use `APIView` in the `post` method to achieve it, but that can not fit the simplicity and convenience of DRF. so I want in the DRF to do that, is it possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this:
http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#writing-create-methods-for-nested-representations

```
def create(self, validated_data):
        validated_data['task_type'] = 'Initialed'
        server_task = ServerTask.objects.create(**validated_data)
        return server_task
```

Or in your case you may just want a `default` value on the model.

Comment: Do you mean its impossible to set property value in the perform_create? only can do this is `create` method?

Comment: @qg_java一坨子给你中疼 It's not impossible you can modify result of `server_task = serializer.save()` just my personal preference would be to put it in the serializer but i guess depends on use case

Comment: If I rewrite `create` method, should I still write the `queryset = ServerTask.objects.all()` in my CreateAPIView?